# My header moves when changing the page, tell me how to fix it

Tags: html, css, header, head

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title> 
    <style>
    body{
    background-color: white;
}
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.h2body{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;

}

    header{
    
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(128, 96, 101);
}
ul{
    margin-left: 350px;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
ul a{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
nav ul a:hover{
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.cart{
    margin-left: 250px;
    display: flex;
}
.cart section{
    margin-top: 8px;
}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="index.html" class="h2body"><p>CLL</p></a>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <a href="./index.html"><li class="linav">Home</li></a>
                <a href="../about/about.html"><li class="linav">About</li></a> 
                <a href="../contacts/Contacts.html"><li class="linav">Contacts</li></a>
                <a href="../contacts/Contacts.html"><li class="linav">Products</li></a>
                
            </ul>
            <div class="cart">
            <a href=""><img src="icons8-cart-32.png" alt="go to cart"></a> <section>(0)</section>
        </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

My header moves when changing the page, tell me how to fix it!

I tried giving the header position: fixed value, but that didn't help. I want that when changing pages, the header did not change the location by a couple of pixels, please help. in particular, the title and the sheet are shifted by 17 pixels! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can You clarify in what way it 'moves'

Answer (score 0):

I fixed one issue. When you hover over the links it will not increase the header height anymore.

The change I had made here is:

```
ul a{
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    /* So that it can occupy that 1px initially and will not increase the height on hover */
}
```

And for the top link clickablility issue:

I changed the display of the a tag to `inline-block` so that it doesn't take the whole block and for positioning I had to add a container with flex display and had to add a fixed height. Here are the list of changes:

```
.h2body{display: inline-block;}

.h2body-container{
    height: 72px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

And in the html markup you can see the a container with "h2body-container" class

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title> 
    <style>
    body{
    background-color: white;
}
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.h2body-container{
    height: 72px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.h2body{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
}

    header{
    
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(128, 96, 101);
}
ul{
    margin-left: 350px;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
ul a{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;   
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
nav ul a:hover{
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.cart{
    margin-left: 250px;
    display: flex;
}
.cart section{
    margin-top: 8px;
}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="h2body-container"><a href="index.html" class="h2body"><p>CLL</a></div>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <a href="./index.html"><li class="linav">Home</li></a>
                <a href="../about/about.html"><li class="linav">About</li></a> 
                <a href="../contacts/Contacts.html"><li class="linav">Contacts</li></a>
                <a href="../contacts/Contacts.html"><li class="linav">Products</li></a>
                
            </ul>
            <div class="cart">
            <a href=""><img src="icons8-cart-32.png" alt="go to cart"></a> <section>(0)</section>
        </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://imagetolink.com/ib/zX2iI9Ungc
https://imagetolink.com/ib/8noOh0WYHG

Comment: OK, got the issue and updated. Please Run the code snippet and check the codes.

Comment: i got it! thank you :3

Comment: If it helps then you can upvote and mark this answer as "Accepted Answer" if you want.